# Sampling uniformly from a ball in SPD manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, measure-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

I'm trying to sample uniformly from a ball around the identity matrix in the manifold of symmetric positive-definite matrices (SPD), i.e., $\mathcal{B}(R) = \{X \in \mathcal{P}(n) : d_\mathcal{P}(I_n, X) \le R\}$, where $\mathcal{P}(n)$ is endowed with the usual metric, $ds = \lVert X^{-1} dX \rVert_F$. I'm getting some unexpected results and the question is **what exactly is the issue with the approach described below (if any)**?

---

I've recently learned (from a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3348558/261538)) that this can be achieved by sampling from a density $p(X) \propto \sqrt{\det g(X)}$ where $g$ is the Riemannian metric in some [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates). (I'm using the suggested rejection sampling approach for this.)

Additionally, I've learned about the following identity concerning the Riemannian metric of the SPD manifold (see, e.g., [ref, Prop.1]),

$$\det(g(X)) = 2^{n (n - 1) / 2} \det(X)^{n + 1}.$$

Now, given that this is a homogeneous space, I'm restricting to sampling around the identity matrix. Then, each matrix $X$ can be represented in the exponential chart at $I_n$ as $P = \log X$, with $P$ a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. The density that I want to sample from is then,

$$p(X) \propto \exp\Big(\frac{n+1}{2} \mathop{\textrm{Tr}} \log X\Big).$$

The **surprising result** that makes me check the correctness of my approach is that the pairwise distances between the sampled matrices are **mostly less than** the radius $R$:

[image]

The distance is given by $d_\mathcal{P}^2(X, Y) = \lVert \log X^{-1/2} Y X^{-1/2} \rVert_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \log^2 \lambda_i(X^{-1} Y)$, where $\lambda_i(P)$ denotes the $i$th eigenvalue of the matrix $P$ (here and below).

From the above formulas, I can see why this happens: being at most $R$-away from $I_n$ means
$$
d_\mathcal{P}^2(I_n, X) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log^2 \lambda_i(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log^2 \exp(\lambda_i(\log X)) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2(\log X) \le R,
$$
while large density mass is assigned to matrices with large values of
$$
\mathop{\textrm{Tr}} \log X = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(\log X).
$$

This seems analogous to sampling uniformly from the unit disk/ball and then weighing the positive quadrant/octant (exponentially) more -- only that in the spectrum space. **Is this really the case or am I misapplying or misinterpreting some of the references from above**?

Thank you.

---

[ref]: Moakher, Maher, and Mourad Zéraï. "The Riemannian geometry of the space of positive-definite matrices and its application to the regularization of positive-definite matrix-valued data." Journal of Mathematical Imaging and Vision 40.2 (2011): 171-187.

Comment: Actually, the determinant of the metric tensor might be wrong.  I found another reference that derives a different expression: http://www-sop.inria.fr/asclepios/cours/MVA/Module2/chapter3.pdf (top of page 25).